# vuelidate required function - Vye.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuelidate

I use vuelidate plugin:

```
import { required, maxLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';
```

I have method

```
methods: {
  isFinishedFill() {
    return !!this.disabledFinishedAt || !!this.finishedAtYear;
  }
}
```

And I have vuelidate plugin. I want send `required` my function, but I get error.

```
validations: {
  finishedAtYear: {
    required: this.isFinishedFill,
  },
}
```

How I can send required function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom validator like so :

```
  import { required, maxLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';
  //custom validator
  const isFinishedFill =(value, vm) =>  !!vm.disabledFinishedAt || !!vm.finishedAtYear;
   //vm represents the Vue instance 
  export default{
      ...
     validations:{
            finishedAtYear: {
               required,
               isFinishedFill  //<---- use  your custom validator
           }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on example provided by [docs](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-simplest-example) try to rewrite you code like this

```
validations: {
    finishedAtYear: {
        isFinishedFill: this.isFinishedFill,
    },
}
```

Or use pure function

```
validations: {
    finishedAtYear: {
        isFinishedFill: (value) => { /* do some checks here */ },
    },
}
```